# Equivalent to gconf on OSX

Tags: macos, gconf

Is there something equivalent (and available by default) to `gconf` on OSX?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OS X uses a "defaults" system, and reads/writes application preferences as "plist" (property list) files that are stored in `~/Library/Preferences`. You can read more about the defaults system [here](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/UserDefaults/UserDefaults.html%23//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000059i).